# Convert char byte to integer value

Tags: c++

For example , **130ABF** (Hexadecimal) is equals to **1247935** (Decimal),
So my byte array is

```
 char buf[3] = {0x13 , 0x0A , 0xBF};
```

and I need to retrieve the decimal value from the byte array.

Below are my sample code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char buf[3] = {0x13 , 0x0A , 0xBF};
    int number = buf[0]*0x10000 + buf[1]*0x100 + buf[2];
    cout<<number<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and the result is : (Wrong)

```
1247679
```

Unless I change the

```
char buf[3] = {0x13 , 0x0A , 0xBF};
```

to

```
int buf[3] = {0x13 , 0x0A , 0xBF};
```

then It will get correct result.

Unfortunately, I must set my array as **char** type,  anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: Are you aware of endianess? You're assuiming a big endian format actually.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Good point, though the way he computes the integer is endianness independant. I'm assuming he means "handwritten hexadecimal representation"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define the array as:

```
unsigned char buf[3];
```

Remember that char could be signed.

UPDATE: In order to complete the answer, it is interesting to add that "char" is a type that could be equivalent to "signed char" or "unsigned char", but it is not determined by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Array elements will be promouted to `int` before evaluating. So if your compiler treats `char` as signed you get next (assuming `int` is 32-bit):

```
int number = 19*0x10000 + 10*0x100 + (-65);
```

To avoid such effect you can declare your array as `unsigned char arr[]`, or use masking plus shifts:

```
int number = ((buf[0] << 16) & 0xff0000)
           | ((buf[1] <<  8) & 0x00ff00)
           | ((buf[2] <<  0) & 0x0000ff;
```

Comment: If char is signed, the third one will be a large negative number

Comment: @M.M Oh, yes. My bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your char array is signed, when you want to initialize the last element (`0xBF`), you are trying to assign 191 to it while the max it can store is 127: a narrowing conversion occurs... A workaround would be the following:

```
unsigned char[3] = { 0x13, 0x0A, 0xBF };
```

This will prevent the narrowing conversion. Your compiler should have given you a warning about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
char buf[3] = {0x13 , 0x0A , 0xBF};
union{
unsigned int ui32;
struct{
    unsigned char ll;
    unsigned char lh;
    unsigned char hl;
    unsigned char hh;
    }splitter;
}combine;
combine.ui32 = 0;
combine.splitter.hl = buf[0];
combine.splitter.lh = buf[1];
combine.splitter.ll = buf[2];

cout << combine.ui32 << endl
```

This should solve your problem.